# What does the parentheses syntax mean in this Table class?

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, slick

The codes are pasted below:

```
class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, String, Int, String)](tag, "suppliers") {
  def snum  = column[String]("snum")
  def sname = column[String]("sname")
  def status   = column[Int]("status")
  def city     = column[String]("city")
  def * = (snum, sname, status, city)
}
```

I know the first parentheses `(tag: Tag)` means the parameter list of `Suppliers`, and the second part `Table[(String, String, Int, String)]` means a `super class with generic`.

But what does `(tag, "suppliers")` mean? Is it a decorator to the superclass `Table` or the defined class `Supplier`. Is there any document about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just calls the constructor of `Table[(String, String, Int, String)]`.

Table's constructor takes a Tag and a String. extends Table( tag, "suppliers ) just wires the required values into the constructor (optionally with added type ascription). This is a standard Scala mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

It is a constructor equivalent to something like below:

```
class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, String, Int, String)]{
  def snum  = column[String]("snum")
  def sname = column[String]("sname")
  def status   = column[Int]("status")
  def city     = column[String]("city")
  def * = (snum, sname, status, city)
  def this(tag:Tag) {
    super(tag, "suppliers")


}

}
```